# Why is the From line not working on my mail function?

Tags: php, html, email, mime

I am using a mail function to send html to an email address, but the From name and email address aren't showing up. This is my code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mailTo = 'name@email.com';
$subject = 'Message from ' . $_POST['name'];
$message = 
            '<html>
            <head>
            <title>HTML email</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <p><b>Name:</b> ' . $_POST['name'] . '</p>
            <p><b>Email:</b> ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>
            <p><b>Message:</b> ' . $_POST['mainmessage'] . '</p>
            </body>
            </html>';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Postmaster <some@body.com>';

mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I would expect the email to show up as being from Postmaster at the email address some@body.com, but it is showing up as coming from ideapale@box486.bluehost.com, which is my hosting provider.

What did I not set up correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris, try adding the `\r\n` after the `<some@body.com>`. I've found that php can be very picky when talking to mail servers.

Edit: just to help a little more, I have this (almost exactly what you have) in one of my working scripts:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: '.$to . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' .$from. "\r\n";
```

...where `$from = $fromname.' <'.$fromemail.'>';` and $to is just an email address.